# My component can be stricter than me

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

My component can be stricter than me.

I'm used to read from not a wire, but a wave.
You may use me where I'm used, an example is right in front of your eyes,
and I am alive, though some parts have died.

Hint:

> What does warspyking like to post?

Hint 2:

> Hint 3 means you can actually see it working now

Spoiler:

> My sibling is JavaScript (put this as a spoiler because if it were hint it would be obvious)

Comment: Spoiler is the answer?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 5):

Is it a

> Wifi-Chip?

My predecessor and my component can be stricter than me

> Before Wi-Fi, accessing the internet was much more difficult (Ethernet cables aren't everywhere).

I'm used to read from not a wire, but a wave

> Wi-Fi pulls data from the internet using waves and satellites.

You may use me where I'm used, an example is right in front of your eyes,

> To view this question, your computer is likely using a Wi-Fi chip to access the internet.

and I am alive, though some parts have died

> Not sure though perhaps some parts of the chip are now obsolete that weren't before? Or the entire chip isn't being used?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and good answer! c:

Comment: No. Good try. Look at the hint!

Answer (score 3):

You are

> An LCD screen

My predecessor and my component can be stricter than me

> The predecessor to LCD screens, Plasma screens, were more "strict" and one had to be careful with them: if you left one picture on the screen for too long, it would burn permanently into the pixels (this is not an issue with LCD screens, however).

I'm used to be read from not a wire, but a wave.

> Visible light (which is how humans read LCD screens) is a type of Electromagnetic wave.

You may use me where I'm used, an example is right in front of your eyes.

> Most computers and smartphones use LCD screens and that's how you are viewing this.

I am alive, though some parts have died.

> LCD screens are still alive and well, but some smartphones (parts of the screen industry) like the Samsung Galaxy S7 and Nexus 6P now use AMOLED screens (not LCD screens), meaning some devices have killed off their use of LCD screens.

Comment: Unfortunetly, also wrong :(

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow User [warspyking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3979429/warspyking) has this as Top Tag.

> Language **Lua**

My predecessor and my component can be stricter than me.

> Language C is predecessor and component of Lua, is stricter.

I'm used to read from not a wire, but a wave.

> Lua can be used to read WAVE audio files

You may use me where I'm used, an example is right in front of you're eyes,

> Used in making/programming video games, and games are right in front of your eyes on screen.

and I am alive, though some parts have died.

> Maybe Lua is being used in some things and have become obsolete in others.

Comment: Sorry, "can be stricter than me" means one is, and the other you can choose.

Comment: @RayWu Is the answer 'scripting language' OR 'Embedded scripting language ' and not Lua?

Comment: Not exactly scripting language.