# I am what a kernel runs in — What am I

Tags: computer-science

I am what a kernel runs in.
I block the kernel from accessing the screen.
You must make a driver in another one of me to use the screen.
My name is found in Windows, Apples too.
Spoiler:

> Both Siri and Cortana have similar logos.

Comment: The kernel has total control of the system. What could possible prevent it from using any computer resource?

Comment: @RadoslavHristov I suppose he meant as in control it? That was slightly confusing

Comment: This isn't really a puzzle, is it? It's just "identify this thing".

Comment: Hint: It's part of the assembly compiler. (A security feature)

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a straight description of an object without any puzzle elements.

Comment: @f'' That's not *entirely* true, it has a few puzzle elements

Comment: Why don't you say it's a riddle?

Comment: Please explain what different it is to [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38734/my-component-can-be-stricter-than-me/38742#38742)

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> OS(Operating System)

I am what the kernel runs in:

> The OS uses the kernel to run

I block the kernel from accessing the screen:

> The OS tells the kernel what to draw on screen

You must make a driver in another one of me:

> You use an OS to make a driver for another OS

My name is found is Windows, Apples:

> Windows OS, iOS

Comment: I disagree - the kernel IS part of the OS.

Comment: I thought the kernel was motherboard based? Since that's what interacts with the processor and each OS doesn't have a kernel for every processor. My understanding could be entirely flawed though.

Comment: The kernel is the OS code!

Comment: @RayWu not right then?

Comment: It BLOCKS the kernel from using it!

Comment: Yes. Not right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are a

> boot loader

Because

> that is what initialises the kernel, hence can block the kernel from doing anything - by just not loading it into memory.